# Concatenate regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I am trying to get this all into one query, but my regex skills are not so grand. I did get it to work in this ungraceful manner. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

the source $url would look like this:

```
/o/33484/bob-nonami
```

the end result I need looks like this:

```
bob-nonami
```

This is what could use some efficiency

```
$urlName1 = preg_replace("/[0-9]/","",$url);
$urlName2 = preg_replace("/(o)/","",$urlName1);
$urlName = preg_replace("/(\/)/","",$urlName2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the other characters in your [character class](http://php.net/regexp.reference.character-classes) for replacement.

```
$url = "/o/33484/bob-nomai";
echo preg_replace("~^/o[0-9/]+~", "", $url); // bob-nomai
```

There's no way you're doing `preg_replace("/(o)/", "", $urlName1)` because that would just result in getting the string `"bb-nmai"`, which clearly isn't what you want.

Instead, you seem to want to remove the leading `"/o"` at the begging of the string, which can be achieved in [PCRE with an anchor](http://php.net/regexp.reference.anchors).

> Outside a character class, in the default matching mode, the circumflex character (^) is an assertion which is true only if the current matching point is at the start of the subject string.

So `^/o` will match the `/o` at the beginning of the subject and any proceeding characters of `[0-9/]`.

Comment: /(o)/ is not what i wanted. you are right! your example is exactly what was needed. Thanx so much!! :)